# Извлечь питоновские файлы из исполняемого

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

Создал с помощью `pyinstaller` экзешник из питоновского файла. Можно ли получить из него изначальный питоновский файл?

Пробовал разные утилиты в интернете, но ни одна не выдала исходный файл, обычно названия функций и байты, которые непонятно как читать.

Comment: [Пробовали?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/164)

Comment: @КириллМалышев видел этот ответ, но там битая ссылка

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы изменили .spec файл под создание чистого exe-шника, то вряд ли сможете посмотреть исходник. А если дефолтная установка, то можно в корневой папке посмотреть, откуда делается сама программа.

Comment: Какой папке и что посмотреть? Устанавливал через `pyinstaller -D` из обычного `.py` файла без `.spec`

Comment: https://codecamp.ru/blog/python-pyinstaller-distributing-python-code/